# Call a function by input type submit with the value of another input element

Tags: javascript, html, ping

I have this code that calls a function on key up but I don't want it to be called so often because if you enter a domain name keyup is triggered very often, so I made a submit button but I don't know how I can call the function with the value of the first input tag.. I did that with this.value first but that probably won't work on the other element. Thanks for any help

```
<form>
Hostname: <input type="text" id="input" onkeyup="ping(this.value)">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

*how I can call the function with the value of the first input tag..*

You can try `querySelector()` that matches the first element:

```
document.querySelector('input[type=text]').value
```

**Demo:**

```js
function ping(v){
  console.log(v)
}
```

```html
<form>
Hostname: <input type="text" id="input">
<input type="submit" onclick="ping(document.querySelector('input[type=text]').value)">
</form>
```

Comment: This also executes the function onkeyup

Comment: I want to execute it on a button click

Comment: @Linus, in that case use click event on the button, updated the answer, please check:)

Comment: Thanks for your help, now the POST request looks like this: "domain.tld/example/example.php?q=ping" with an input of "domaintechnik.at" but it should look like this "domain.tld/example/example.php?q=domaintechnik.at". It worked before @Mamun